# Exercise about primary ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

For a fixed prime ideal $\mathfrak p$ in the ring $A$ consider the canonical ring homomorphism $A\to A_\mathfrak p$ to the local ring $A_\mathfrak p$ and write $I\cap A$ for the contraction of any ideal $I\subseteq A_\mathfrak p$. Set $\mathfrak p ^{(n)} := \mathfrak p ^nA_\mathfrak p\cap A$. Show that for every $n\gt 1$ the ideal $\mathfrak p ^{(n)}$ is primary in $A$.

My problem is that I don't understand why this ideal $\mathfrak p ^{(n)}$ isn't just the ideal $\mathfrak p ^n\subseteq A$, since $\mathfrak p ^n\subseteq \mathfrak p ^nA_\mathfrak p$ and from the other side any element of $\mathfrak p ^nA_\mathfrak p$ in $A$ must be an element of $\mathfrak p ^n $ (it seems to me). What do I misunderstand? Thanks for any clearing

Comment: “It seems to me” is a pretty loose argument. Can you flesh that out?

Comment: I said also "in $A$", I mean those elements of $\mathfrak p ^n A_\mathfrak p$ whose numerator is divisible by the denominator.

Comment: note that $A \rightarrow A_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is not necessarily injective...

Comment: How can the map $a\to \frac a1$ not be injective, can you make me an example?

Comment: What I meant is that every element $a\in \mathfrak p $ corresponds to an element $\frac a1\in \mathfrak p^n A_\mathfrak p$, and for every element $\frac ab\in \mathfrak p^n A_\mathfrak p$ such that $a$ is divisible by $b$, $a$ must be in $\mathfrak p^n$. And so, it seems to me that the ideals $\mathfrak p^{(n)}$ and $\mathfrak p^{n}$ coincide, but I know that I'm wrong somewhere.

Comment: You need, for your "It seems to me" that if $a\in A$ and $ba\in\mathfrak p^n$ with $b\notin \mathfrak p$ then $a\in\mathfrak p^n.$ If you don't have this, then $\frac{ab}{b}\in A\cap\mathfrak p^nA_{\mathfrak p},$ but $a\notin\mathfrak p^n.$ It's not clear how to prove that $a\in\mathfrak p^n.$

Comment: If you localize $A=\mathbb Z/\langle 6\rangle$ at the prime ideal $\mathfrak p=2A,$ then $A_{\mathfrak p}\cong \mathbb Z/\langle 2\rangle.$ So $A\to A_{\mathfrak p}$ need not be an injection. It is an injection if $A$ is an integral domain. See the "general construction" in the wikipedia page. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localization_(commutative_algebra)

Comment: In general, you can check that the canonical map $\varphi : A \to S^{-1}A$ is injective iff $S$ does not contain any zero divisors. Indeed, $\varphi$ is not injective iff there exists $a \neq 0$ such that $\frac a 1 = 0$ iff there exists $s \in S$ and $a \neq 0$ such that $sa = 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the canonical ring homomorphism $\varphi:A\to A_\mathfrak p$, $\varphi(a)=\frac a1$. Then $\varphi^{-1}(\mathfrak p^nA_{\mathfrak p})=\{a\in A:\frac a1\in\mathfrak p^nA_{\mathfrak p}\}$. But $\frac a1\in\mathfrak p^nA_{\mathfrak p}$ means that there is $x\in\mathfrak p^n$ and $s\in A\setminus\mathfrak p$ such that $\frac a1=\frac xs$. Then there is $t\in A\setminus\mathfrak p$ such that $tsa=tx$. We can rephrase this as follows: there is $u\in A\setminus\mathfrak p$ such that $ua\in\mathfrak p^n$, so $$\mathfrak p ^{(n)}=\{a\in A:\exists u\in A\setminus\mathfrak p\text{ such that } ua\in\mathfrak p^n\}.$$

Of course, $\mathfrak p^n\subseteq\mathfrak p ^{(n)}$, but the inclusion can be strict. For instance, a prime ideal $\mathfrak p$ with $\mathfrak p^2$ not primary satisfies $\mathfrak p^2\subsetneq\mathfrak p ^{(2)}$.