# Showing that a primary ideal is minimal

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals, primary-decomposition

Like in my previous question ([Exercise about primary ideals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4296687/exercise-about-primary-ideals)), consider the canonical homomorphism $A\to A_\mathfrak p$, for a fixed prime ideal $\mathfrak p$ in the ring $A$, and write $I\cap A$ for the contraction of any ideal $I\subseteq A_\mathfrak p$. Show that if a $\mathfrak p $-primary ideal contains $\mathfrak p^n$, then it contains $\mathfrak p ^{(n)} := \mathfrak p ^nA_\mathfrak p\cap A$.

Take $\mathfrak q\supseteq \mathfrak p^n$ a $\mathfrak p$-primary ideal: if $a\in \mathfrak p^{(n)}$, exists a $b\in A\setminus \mathfrak p$ such that $ab\in \mathfrak p^n$, i.e. $ab\in \mathfrak q$ and $b\notin \mathfrak q$. However this proves that $a\in \sqrt {\mathfrak q}=\mathfrak p$, not that $a\in \mathfrak q$. Can you just give me an hint?

Comment: You made a mistake when wrote $b\notin \mathfrak q$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathfrak q\supseteq \mathfrak p^n$ be a $\mathfrak p$-primary ideal and $a\in \mathfrak p^{(n)}$. There exists $s\in A\setminus \mathfrak p$ such that $sa\in \mathfrak p^n$, hence $sa\in \mathfrak q$ and $s\notin \mathfrak p$. It follows that $a\in \mathfrak q$.